# In C, how to set first eight bits of any sized int in a generic way

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How do I set the first (least significant) eight bits of any integer type to all zeroes? Essentially do a bitwise AND of any integer type with `0x00`.

What I need is a generic solution that works on any integer size, but not have to create a mask setting all the higher bits to `1`.

In other words:

```
0xffff             & 0x00 = 0xff00
0xaabbccddeeffffff & 0x00 = 0xaabbccddeeffff00
```

Comment: I think integer size is always greater 1byte

Comment: `the first 8 bits` just to be sure, the "first 8 bits" are the _least_ significant bits?

Comment: _first 8 bits_ mean 0 to 7 or 31 to 24 ?

Comment: Based on the sample data, OP wishes to zero out the least significant eight bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution works for all integer types on architectures with 2's complement representation for negative numbers:

```
val = val & ~0xff;
```

The reason is `~0xff` evaluates to `-256` with type `int`. Let's consider all possible types for `val`:

- if the type of `val` is smaller than `int`, `val` is promoted to `int`, the mask operation works as expected and the result is converted back to the type of `val`.
- if the type of `val` is signed, `-256` is converted to type of `val` preserving its value, hence replicating the sign bit, and the mask is performed properly.
- If the type of `val` is unsigned, converting `-256` to this type produces the value `TYPE_MAX + 1 - 256` that has all bits set except the 8 low bits, again the proper mask for the operation.

Another simple solution, that works for all representations of negative values is this:

```
val = val ^ (val & 0xff);
```

It requires storing the value into a variable to avoid multiple evaluation, whereas the first proposal can be applied to any expression with potential side-effects:

```
return my_function(a, b, c) & ~0xff;
```

Answer (score 4):

With bit shifts:

```
any_unsigned_integer = any_unsigned_integer >> 8 << 8;
```

Comment: Your second proposal would not work for `unsigned long long` if this type is larger than `unsigned long`. `any_unsigned_integer &= ~0xffull;` is better but would still not work for a `uint128_t` if available.

Comment: @chqrlie: I think KamilCuk may have been suggesting you use a mask type appropriate to the variable being modified, not `unsigned long` always. Hence `(uint128_t)0xff` for variables of type `unit128_t`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: that is not my reading of *What I need is a generic solution that works on any integer size, but not have to create a mask setting all the higher bits to 1.* A generic solution should work unmodified for all types, and I believe such a solution exists and is simple.

Answer (score 2):

The C not operator `~` will invert all the bits of a given value so, in order to get a mask that will clear only the lower eight bits:

```
int val = 123456789;
int other_val = val & ~0xff; // AND with binary 1111 ... 1111 0000 0000
val &= ~0xff;                // alternative to change original variable.
```

If you have a wider (or thinner) type, the `0xff` should be of the correct type, for example:

```
long val = 123456789L;
long other_val = val & ~(long)0xff;
val &= ~(long)0xff;          // alternative to change original variable.
```

Comment: The 2nd lines of your examples don't make sense. They are declarations of (uninitialized) variables upon which you do run-time operations.

Comment: @Paul, yes, I originally had `value &= blah` but changed them to not affect the original variable. Badly, as it turned out :-) Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without a creating a mask for the higher bits is to use a combination of the `&` and `^` operators: `x = x ^ (x & 0xFF);` (or, using compound assignment: `x ^= x & 0xFF;`).

Comment: 0xff is actually the mask so  `without a creating a mask` is not the truth.

Comment: @0___________ The mask is for the lower bits that are being changed. I believe the requirement is for the mask not to have higher bits set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Universal solution no mask, any number of bits

```
#define RESETB(val, nbits) ((val) ^ ((val) & ((1ULL << (nbits)) - 1)))
```

or even better

```
#define RESETB(val, nbits) ((val) ^ ((val) & ((nbits) ? ((nbits) >= sizeof(val) * CHAR_BIT ? ((1ULL << (sizeof(val) * CHAR_BIT)) - 1) : ((1ULL << (nbits)) - 1)) : 0)))
```

Comment: @chqrlie Indeed, did not read carefully enough, amended

Comment: These macros will evaluate their first argument twice.